# Android O: New font directory and usage

Tags: android

I'm implementing the new Android O font in XML feature according to this guide: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

I've created the `font` directory and added my 4 font files and created a font resource file `newfont.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="regular"
        android:font="@font/NewFont_Rg" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="medium"
        android:font="@font/NewFont_Md" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="bold"
        android:font="@font/NewFont_Bd" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="condensed"
        android:font="@font/NewFont_Cd" />
</font-family>
```

Now I've added the font family to my style:

```
<style name="HeadlineBig">
    <item name="android:textSize">84sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/newfont</item>
</style>
```

The question is, how do I specify **in the style** which of the font styles to use? `regular`, `medium`, `bold` or `condensed`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style would be

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/NewFont_Rg</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/NewFont_Md</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/NewFont_Bd</item>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting many errors concerning my font (which don't make any sense since I've been using these fonts programmatically 'the old way' with no errors), so I think I'll wait a few months until this feature matures. Your answer is probably correct so thanks anyways.

Comment: @Ambran It worked for me. But till now code is not accessible at work. So if you need, I can share you the same code provided by google but have some modification made to run it properly.

Comment: The system insists on not recognizing the type 'font'. Running Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 on Mac and gradle 3.5.